# Spotify API, preload cover arts

Tags: spotify

Im currently having a function that animates a couple of cover arts from some random tracks. The problem I have is that the spotify cover arts lazy loads so the image sometimes doesn't appear since the load takes too long.

So, is there any way to preload the images before i start my animation? Or do i have to "play and stop" every track before my animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` event.

```
$(image.node).on("DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument", function onLoad(){ ... });
```